# What would Repair and Optimize Wordpress Database do?

Tags: database, optimization

Recently I am getting an error establishing a database connection in a clients Wordpress site. I googled for a solution and an article suggested to enable Wordpress Repairs by adding this to the wp-config.php file:

`define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);`

After that, visit the link:

`http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php`

And allowing repair as follow:

[image: WordPress Database Repair Tool UI]

So my question is. What does **optimization** mean? What are those scenarios or situations that Wordpress fix? Can I do this procedure in existing and non problematic Wordpress websites to enhance performance?

Comment: As far as I know it does not do anything more than running mysql command for optimizing and repairing damaged mysql tables. Sometimes tables corrupt and mysql has inbuilt option `mysqlcheck -r` to repair and `mysqlcheck -o` to optimize a mysql database. WordPress just run those commands. For more details on these two you can search on mysql docs.